# Where should javascript go in Wordpress which is only necessary for single.php?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I want to add social buttons (Facebook, Twitter, G+) at the end of a post in a Wordpress site I'm building. They only need to be shown on a post's permalink page (which is edited in single.php).

So, my question is, should I put the necessary scripts in header.php (which would put them in place but they would always load even when not necessary), or should I put them somewhere in single.php (which would mean they only load when necessary but are located somewhere in the middle of `<body>`)?

Comment: Move to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has a [function called `is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) which returns if you are dealing with a single page at the moment.

You could include the scripts only if a single page is viewed. You could do it with

```
<?php if (is_single()) : ?>
  <script src="http://twitter.com/path/to/bla"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You may want to load scripts at the end of the page (right before the closing `body`-tag) as it lets the page render before loading the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use the wp_enqueue_scripts action hook. You should always use this to avoid conflicts and keep all the goodness that comes with it.

I slightly modified an [example from the doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_script_from_your_theme_which_depends_upon_a_WordPress_Script) to illustrate this:

```
<?php
 function my_scripts_method() {
 if(is_single()){
  // register your script location, dependencies and version
  wp_register_script('custom_script',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
    array('jquery'),
    '1.0' );
  // enqueue the script
  wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with adding script elements mixed in the middle of the `body`, however if you want to improve loading times, you might want to append the `script` elements to `footer.php`. Having scripts called after the rest of the dom has loaded will prevent the loading of the scripts from blocking the rest of the page from rendering.

If it's a very small script, I see no reason not to just add them inline where it'll be easy to see what elements they affect.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them at the bottom of your single.php, but as you point out this would leave them appearing mid-page.

Instead, put them in your header.php, but insider an if statement to check that they are needed (i.e. it is a single page), like so:

```
<?php if (is_single()): ?>
     <script>...</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

The first `<?php` and last `?>` wil not be necessary / may cause problems if you put the above code insider php tags. Either way, inside the if statement, should be HTML, not php for this to work.